# Reset rowcolors of table

Tags: tables, multirow, rowcolor

I had some tables with alternating row coloring, using `\rowcolors{1}{white}{gray}` and tabular environment. After that, I wanted to reset my rowcolors to the default, so I did `\rowcolors{1}{white}{white}`. However, when I tried to use multirow, I still had the problem with the overlapping background.
I know that I can use a negative index, as in an alternating colored table, but my question is, how can I reset colors to default?

When I have a clean latex document, I can use multirow without negative indexes. Can I somehow get back to that after I used `rowcolors` command?

```
\rowcolors{1}{white}{gray}

**tables and other code**

\begin{table}[H]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\rowcolors{1}{white}{white}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | c | c | }
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{teeeeeeeeest} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\hline
& 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could surround your preceesing tables with `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`. The `\rowcolor` command will then be just active inside of this group. Other commands that change for example font size, font color, thickness of lines,... will also be affected and will only be active inside of this group.

I thus also included a second option, that locally resets the `\rowcolor` command for just this one table by using `\rowcolors{1}{}{}` instead of `\rowcolors{1}{white}{white}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}

\begingroup
\rowcolors{1}{white}{gray}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
text & text \\
text & text \\
text & text \\
text & text \\
text & text \\
\end{tabular}

**tables and other code**

\begin{tabular}{ll}
text & text \\
text & text \\
text & text \\
text & text \\
text & text \\
\end{tabular}
\endgroup

\begin{table}[H]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | c | c | }
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{teeeeeeeeest} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\hline
& 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}



\rowcolors{1}{white}{gray}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
text & text \\
text & text \\
text & text \\
text & text \\
text & text \\
\end{tabular}

**tables and other code**

\begin{tabular}{ll}
text & text \\
text & text \\
text & text \\
text & text \\
text & text \\
\end{tabular}


\begin{table}[H]
\rowcolors{1}{}{}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | c | c | }
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{teeeeeeeeest} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\hline
& 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, we have the possibility to fix exactly the scope of your command `\rowcolors`. You have also a command `\Block` which is easy to use everywhere to replace `\multicolumn` and `\multirow` (however, those commands are still available if you want).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cc}[hvlines]
\CodeBefore
  \rowlistcolors{4-10}{red!15,blue!15}
\Body
AAAAAAAA & 333 \\
BBBBB & 444 \\
AAAAAAAA & 333 \\
BBBBB & 444 \\
AAAAAAAA & 333 \\
BBBBB & 444 \\
AAAAAAAA & 333 \\
BBBBB & 444 \\
AAAAAAAA & 333 \\
BBBBB & 444 \\
AAAAAAAA & 333 \\
BBBBB & 444 \\
AAAAAAAA & 333 \\
BBBBB & 444 \\
\Block{2-1}{CCC} & 333 \\
                 & 444 \\
AAAAAAAA & 333 \\
BBBBB & 444 \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/TikZ nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

It's also possible (in a version of `nicematrix` at least 6.25) to place a command `\rowlistcolors` somewhere in the tabular and place a command `\rowlistcolors{}` further to stop the coloring.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cc}[hvlines,color-inside]
AAAAAAAA & 333 \\
BBBBB & 444 \\
AAAAAAAA & 333 \\
BBBBB & 444 \\
\rowlistcolors{red!15,blue!15}
AAAAAAAA & 333 \\
BBBBB & 444 \\
AAAAAAAA & 333 \\
BBBBB & 444 \\
AAAAAAAA & 333 \\
BBBBB & 444 \\
\rowlistcolors{}
AAAAAAAA & 333 \\
BBBBB & 444 \\
AAAAAAAA & 333 \\
BBBBB & 444 \\
\Block{2-1}{CCC} & 333 \\
                 & 444 \\
AAAAAAAA & 333 \\
BBBBB & 444 \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.